# What does HttpResponseMessage return as Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a basic question about basics on Web Api. FYI, I have checked before but could not found what I was looking for.

I have a piece of code as described below these lines. Just like any other Method in general terms my method called: Post, it has to return something,a JSON for example, How do I do that. 
Specifically, what am I supposed to write after the word " return " in order to get the 3 fields( loginRequest.Username,loginRequest.Password,loginRequest.ContractItemId ) as Json.
Coments: Do not worry about username,password and contractID are in comments, I do get their value in my LinQ. It's just the return whta I nened now, greetings to all who would like to throw some notes about this.

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(LoginModel loginRequest)
    {
        //loginRequest.Username = "staw_60";
        //loginRequest.Password = "john31";
        //loginRequest.ContractItemId = 2443;

      try
        {
           Membership member =
                (from m in db.Memberships
                 where
                     m.LoginID == loginRequest.Username 
                 && m.Password == loginRequest.Password 
                 && m.ContractItemID == loginRequest.ContractItemId
                 select m).SingleOrDefault();   
        }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
       }

      return ???;      
    }
```

Comment: OT: `catch (Exception e) { throw new Exception(e.Message); }` is a *terrible* idea. Good luck tracking down any errors without a sensible exception type or stack trace!

Comment: @Adriano this isn't MVC this is [Web-API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) so it is a litte different.

Comment: @RichardDeeming I would also include that the proper error handling in this case is to `catch (Exception e) { throw; }`.  I would image the code is there for breakpoint debugging but a breakpoing can still be put on throw and have *debuggablility*.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: I can see the point for debugging the code, but in production code I'd be inclined to leave out the `try...catch` entirely.

Comment: @RichardDeeming or at least actually do something useful, like logging and sending back a `HttpResponseMessage` with a 500 or something.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new ObjectContent<Response>(
        new Response() { 
                        responseCode = Response.ResponseCodes.ItemNotFound 
                       }, 
                       new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");
```

or just create another response from Request object itself.

```
return Request.CreateResponse<Response>(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
      new Response() { responseCode = Response.ResponseCodes.ItemNotFound })
```

You can also turn all your response types to JSON by updating the HttpConfiguration(Formatter.Remove) just remove the default xml serialization and put JSON.

Comment: FYI: You can use `JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType.MediaType` instead of hard coding the media string. ;)

Comment: Why is this method forcing the Content Type?  What if the user of the API prefers requests XML and another prefers JSON?  It would be much preferable to return the type that the request has specified.

Answer (score 17):

You could perhaps create a `LoginResponseModel` class that you can use to send back information to the caller about the success/failure of the login attempt. Something like:

```
public class LoginResponseModel
{
    public bool LoginSuccessful {get; set;}
    public string ErrorMessage {get; set;}
    public LoginResponseModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can return this directly from the controller if you like:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public LoginResponseModel Post(LoginModel loginRequest)
{
    ...

    return new LoginResponseModel() { LoginSuccessful = true, ErrorMessage = "" };
}
```

Or you can still use a `HttpResponseMessage` as return type, but send a `LoginResponseModel` as the json response:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(LoginModel loginRequest)
{
    ...

    var resp = Request.CreateResponse<LoginResponseModel>(
        HttpStatusCode.OK,
        new LoginResponseModel() { LoginSuccessful = true, ErrorMessage = "" }
    );
    return resp;
}
```